# ¿Se puede agregar el mismo ID en los botones eliminar y modificar de una fila?

Tags: javascript

> Estoy usando solamente JavaScript puro, ya que estoy aprendiendo.

¿Es posible agregar el mismo ID en los botones ELIMINAR y EDITAR de una fila? O sea, ¿estoy cumpliendo con buenas prácticas?

¿Me surgirá algún error luego? Si no se puede, ¿cómo sería otra forma?

Yo pensaba usar de última el `"name= producto.codigo"`

```
    function CargarGrilla(_lista) {

    //Obtener la tabla para luego agregar la fila nueva

        let tablaFunko = document.getElementById("tablaFunko");
        let fila = "";
        tablaFunko.innerHTML = "";
        
    //Recorrer lista del LocalStorage e ir agregandolo en la tabla

        for (let item in _lista) {
            //agregar valores en fila
            fila = `<tr onclick="SeleccionarFila(this)">
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            <th>${_lista[item].codigo}</th>
            <td>${_lista[item].nombre}</td>
            <td>${_lista[item].nroSerie}</td>
            <td>${_lista[item].categoria}</td>
            <td>${_lista[item].descripcion}</td>
            <td>${_lista[item].imagen}</td>
     
            <td><button class="mb-1 btn btn-warning" onclick="CargarDatos(this)" id="${_lista[item].codigo}">Editar</button>
            
            <button class="mb-1 btn btn-danger" onclick="Eliminar(this)" id="${_lista[item].codigo}">Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>`;
        //Mi consulta seria al crear los botones, creo un ID con el codigo del producto, para poder reconocerlo. Me funciona pero mi duda es, si es una buena practica
        
            //agregar la fila en la tabla
            tablaFunko.innerHTML += fila;
        }
    }
```

```
<tbody id="tablaFunko">
</tbody>
```

Comment: Un id debe ser único por página. Y si te dará errores, la mayoría de los navegadores tomarán el primer elemento que encuentre con esa ID (esto no es una norma y cualquier navegador podría operar de manera distinta).  En vez ocupar una id, puedes ocupar class o incluso puedes crear tu propio atributo

Comment: Si no te está dando errores en este minuto es porque los handlers `CargarDatos` y `Eliminar`  están operando sobre el elemento, no sobre su identificador.  Lo cual insinúa que no necesitas un identificador. Eso es un vicio que jQuery metió en el 90& de los tutoriales publicados en la web

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Tu pregunta tiende a ser basada en opiniones, por lo tanto podría terminar [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: @ffflabs No entendí tu comentario y a modo de curiosidad, el vicio que señalas que metió jquery es operar sobre el elemento o sobre su identificador? no se a cuál de los 2 te referías

Comment: Mejor redacté una respuesta. Me temo que mi opinión sobre el paradigma que popularizó jQuery no pasa de ser una lectura personal que  no tengo cómo más argumentar.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Es posible agregar el mismo ID en los botones ELIMINAR y EDITAR de una fila? O sea, ¿estoy cumpliendo con buenas prácticas?

Respecto a tu pregunta puntual: el ID de cada elemento debe ser único.

> ¿Me surgirá algún error luego?

Operaciones como [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) y [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) consultan el DOM retornando la primera coincidencia, por lo que las repeticiones de un mismo ID son simplemente inalcanzables para esas api.

> Si no se puede, ¿cómo sería otra forma?

Cómo sería otra forma de qué? De generar identificadores únicos para cada botón? Bueno, podría ser algo como

```
 <button onclick="CargarDatos(this)" id="${_lista[item].codigo}_editar">Editar</button>
 <button onclick="Eliminar(this)" id="${_lista[item].codigo}_eliminar">Eliminar</button></td>
```

Pero como dije en los comentarios ¿Necesitas identificadores? Mi suposición es que `CargarDatos` y `Eliminar` necesitan una referencia a la fila, y una fila se define por su código.

```
CargarDatos(elemento) {
   const codigo=<alguna propiedad del elemento>
}
Eliminar(elemento) {
   const codigo=<alguna propiedad del elemento>
}
```

Entonces tu primer instinto fue poner

```
   const codigo=elemento.id;
```

Y eso efectivamente funciona, porque el handler `onclick` no tiene que pasar por el DOM para referirse a un elemento. Sabe que el elemento es `this`.

Como repetir el ID es incorrecto (por mucho que te funcione), y máxime considerando que quieres mapear un atributo lógico pero que semánticamente no es propio del elemento, lo correcto es usar un [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

```
 <button onclick="CargarDatos(this)" data-codigo="${_lista[item].codigo}">Editar</button>
 <button onclick="Eliminar(this)" data-codigo="${_lista[item].codigo}">Eliminar</button></td>


CargarDatos(elemento) {
   const codigo=elemento.getAttribute('data-codigo');
}
Eliminar(elemento) {
   const codigo=elemento.getAttribute('data-codigo');
}
```

En los comentarios hablé de un "vicio de jQuery". Me refiero a la manera como jQuery popularizó reemplazar los inline handlers (`onclick`) declarando la lógica por separado. Usando el mismo ejemplo con un código cualquiera, jQuery lo haría así:

```
 <button data-codigo="AZZ4555" id="AZZ4555_editar">Editar</button>
 <button data-codigo="AZZ4555" id="AZZ4555_eliminar">Eliminar</button></td>


jQuery('#AZZ4555_editar').on('click',function() {
   const codigo=jQuery(this).data('codigo')
});
jQuery('#AZZ4555_eliminar').on('click',function() {
   const codigo=jQuery(this).data('codigo')
});
```

Me parece evidente que computar un ID sobre un elemento, para ponerlo en un handler, para referenciar un elemento y con ello obtener una propiedad escalar de éste, es darse dos vueltas de más. Pero el contenido final tendría esos handlers repetidos para cada fila. Es un poco ineficiente.

Aunque hay más de una manera de hacer lo que ilustré como "el ejemplo jQuery" es un hecho que jQuery se popularizó en una época donde `document.getElementById` era el único API de comportamiento uniforme entre browsers. Hasta el día de hoy el 80% de los ejemplos en jQuery.com usan el ID del eventTarget. Mucha gente asume que necesita un ID para declarar un handler, y se termina complicando de más computando IDs únicos que no necesitaba.